# how to get data into webView activity when recyclerView Item is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview

**this is adapter class**

```
package com.example.murarilal.xyz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.EventLogTags;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Murarilal on 19-11-2017.
 */

     class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

            private List<ListItem> listItems;
            private Context context;

        public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
            this.listItems = listItems;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            ListItem listItem=listItems.get(position);

            holder.headText.setText(listItem.getHead());
            holder.desText.setText(listItem.getDes());
            holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,ArticleActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("description",);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

          // Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.netfix).resize(900,300).into(holder.imageView);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listItems.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

                public  TextView headText;
                public  TextView desText;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout;
                //public ImageView imageView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                headText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
                desText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
              //  imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

            }
        }

    }
```

**this is the main activity**

```
package com.example.murarilal.xyz;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public List<ListItem>listItems;
    RequestQueue queue;

    private String url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=d6eaad863cc640a7a6864d18196bea9e";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

       recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new Dec(20));
        listItems=new ArrayList<>();

        home();




    }

    public void home()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem item =new ListItem(o.getString("title"),o.getString("description"));

                        listItems.add(item);
                    }
                    adapter=new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
}
```

**Listitem Activity**

```
package com.example.murarilal.xyz;

/**
 * Created by Murarilal on 19-11-2017.
 */
public class ListItem {



     public String head;
     public String des;
    //private String image;



    public ListItem(String head, String des) {
        this.head=head;
     //  this.image=image;
        this.des=des;
    }


    public String getHead() {

        return head;
    }

    public String getDes() {
        return des;
    }


  /* public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }*/
}
```

**what String should i pass in OnclickListener in Myadpater class to get description data in WebView .What Should be the String to be passed in putextra method with Description.or please generally tell me how to pass data between activites when working with api and Json.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting data from your adapter

Take the instance of your object which you want to send and add OR set whatever the properties you want :

```
//ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
```

Then put extra like below when you want to send:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, ArticleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("listItem", listItem);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve it in your ArticleActivity onCreate method get those extras like:

```
ListItem listItem = (ListItem) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listItem");
```

Here you can get all the properties from that listItem object

For example to get description:

```
String description = listItem.getDes();
```

**And note that your class should be implements Serializable:**

```
class ListItem implements Serializable {

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Updated my answer check it

Comment: @devesh Let me know if you facing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ListItem listItem=listItems.get(position);

        holder.headText.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.desText.setText(listItem.getDes());
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent=new Intent(context,ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

      // Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.netfix).resize(900,300).into(holder.imageView);

    }
```

Here you have `intent.putExtra("description",);` where you can pass `listItem.getDes()` like this `intent.putExtra("description", listItem.getDes());` and `ListItem listItem=(ListItem) listItems.get(position);` this line may need casting.

finally it will be

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ListItem listItem=listItems.get(position);

        holder.headText.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.desText.setText(listItem.getDes());
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent=new Intent(context,ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",listItem.getDesc());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

      // Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.netfix).resize(900,300).into(holder.imageView);

    }
```

In the activity where you have webview. Use this to get back the data passed over intent `Intent intent = getIntent();
String description= intent.getStringExtra('description');`
// now you have your data here.

Enjoy :)